# React ReferenceError: process is not defined

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

I am running a react and using env variables for some of the code.
I keep getting this error though:

ReferenceError: process is not defined.

I have tried using an alternate some people suggested to running npm install react-scripts@latest. , but that did not work.(env extension has located at the root of project )

```
import "./FeaturedProducts.scss";
import Card from "../Card/Card";
import axios from "axios";

const FeaturedProducts = ({ type }) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await axios.get(
          process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL + "/products",
          {
            headers: {
              Authorization: "bearer" + process.env.REACT_APP_API_TOKEN,
            },
          }
        );
        setData(res.data.data);
        console.log(data);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="featuredProducts">
      <div className="top">
        <h1>{type} products</h1>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Quibusdam,
          voluptate itaque sed vero quidem asperiores deserunt reprehenderit id
          optio iusto modi cum ipsa eum veritatis, beatae, magni odit delectus
          aut!
        </p>
      </div>
      <div className="bottom">
        {data.map((item) => (
          <Card item={item} key={item.id} />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default FeaturedProducts;
```

Comment: `process` is server-side only. What typically happens to make it work client side is your build tool replaces all references to `process.env.x` with a string value. If it isn't being replaced, your build tool either doesn't support this or it isn't configured correctly. To help, we will need more info around your build process

Answer (score -1):

I think You forget add:

```
require('dotenv').config();
```

Add this line of code somewhere at the beginning of your app.

Comment: still not working